# How to Install Apache thrift 0.13.0

Tags: thrift

Here I have to work on some services which use Apache Thrift 0.13.0, but recently a new version is released and when I use the `brew install thrift` command on the terminal it installs the latest Thrift version i.e 0.14.0.

I am unable to install thrift 0.13.0. So please can anyone direct me on how to install thrift 0.13 using brew (I have the tar.gz file of Thrift 0.13.0)?

Answer (score 11):

This solution worked for me.

Try:

1. `brew tap-new $USER/local-tap`
2. `brew extract --version='0.13.0' thrift $USER/local-tap`
3. `brew install thrift@0.13.0`

Source: https://gist.github.com/tonydeng/02e571f273d6cce4230dc8d5f394493c

Comment: Error: Invalid tap name 'xxxx/local-tap'...

Comment: Error: Could not find thrift! The formula or version may not have existed.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/alberttwong/homebrew-thrift

```
brew install alberttwong/thrift/thrift@0.13
```

Comment: Here another repo with other versions. https://github.com/cartman-kai/homebrew-thrift