# How to install thrift 0.15 on big sur?

Tags: macos, thrift, macos-big-sur

How can I install thrift 0.15.0 on Mac OS Big Sur? I followed the instructions as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66475068/785523) answer but getting the below error

```
dmanna-a02:main dmanna$ brew untap $USER/local-tap --force
Error: No available tap dmanna/local-tap.
dmanna-a02:main dmanna$ brew tap-new $USER/local-tap
Initialized empty Git repository in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dmanna/homebrew-local-tap/.git/
[master (root-commit) 13428b3] Create dmanna/local-tap tap
 3 files changed, 88 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .github/workflows/publish.yml
 create mode 100644 .github/workflows/tests.yml
 create mode 100644 README.md
==> Created dmanna/local-tap
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dmanna/homebrew-local-tap

When a pull request making changes to a formula (or formulae) becomes green
(all checks passed), then you can publish the built bottles.
To do so, label your PR as `pr-pull` and the workflow will be triggered.

dmanna-a02:main dmanna$ brew extract --version='0.15.0' thrift $USER/local-tap
==> Searching repository history
Warning: Calling `cellar` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256` with a `cellar:` argument instead.
Please report this issue to the homebrew/core tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/thrift.rb:14

Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the homebrew/core tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/thrift.rb:16

Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the homebrew/core tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/thrift.rb:17

Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the homebrew/core tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/thrift.rb:18

Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the homebrew/core tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/thrift.rb:19

Warning: Calling `sha256 "digest" => :tag` in a bottle block is deprecated! Use `brew style --fix` on the formula to update the style or use `sha256 tag: "digest"` instead.
Please report this issue to the homebrew/core tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/thrift.rb:20

Error: thrift: undefined method `sha1' for #<SoftwareSpec:0x00007fc41d986f00>
```

I upgraded homebrew to 3.3.4. After that getting the below errors

```
dmanna-a02:main dmanna$ brew untap $USER/local-tap --force
Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the homebrew/core tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/csshx.rb:11

Untapping dmanna/local-tap...
Untapped (31 files, 27.7KB).
dmanna-a02:main dmanna$ brew tap-new $USER/local-tap
Initialized empty Git repository in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dmanna/homebrew-local-tap/.git/
[master (root-commit) a9c5c38] Create dmanna/local-tap tap
 3 files changed, 88 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .github/workflows/publish.yml
 create mode 100644 .github/workflows/tests.yml
 create mode 100644 README.md
==> Created dmanna/local-tap
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dmanna/homebrew-local-tap

When a pull request making changes to a formula (or formulae) becomes green
(all checks passed), then you can publish the built bottles.
To do so, label your PR as `pr-pull` and the workflow will be triggered.
dmanna-a02:main dmanna$ brew extract --version='0.15.0' thrift $USER/local-tap
==> Searching repository history
Error: thrift: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

- MacOS Version - 11.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps that worked for me after upgrading homebrew to 3.3.4

1. brew update
2. brew untap $USER/local-tap --force
3. brew tap-new $USER/local-tap
4. brew extract --version='0.15.0' thrift $USER/local-tap
5. brew install  thrift@0.15.0

5th step gave the below logs

```
==> Installing thrift@0.15.0 from dmanna/local-tap
Error: Your Command Line Tools are too outdated.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.1.
```

Then performed the below steps

```
dmanna-a02:~ dmanna$ softwareupdate --all --install --force
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
No updates are available.
dmanna-a02:~ dmanna$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
Password:
dmanna-a02:~ dmanna$ sudo xcode-select --install
```

Finally installed thrift 0.15.0 using the below command

```
dmanna-a02:~ dmanna$ brew install  thrift@0.15.0
```